# How to parse file with define information

Tags: php

Is it possible to parse file with define information? so if yes can someone give an idea how i can do this?

config.ini

```
[SQL_INFO]
defined("DB_MS") ? null : define("DB_MS", "mysqli");
defined("DB_HOST") ? null : define("DB_HOST", "localhost");

[USER_INFO]
defined("USER_NAME") ? null : define("USER_NAME", "ali");
defined("USER_WEB") ? null : define("USER_WEB", "example.com");

[SITE_INFO]
defined("WEBSITE") ? null : define("WEBSITE", "example.com");
defined("IS_ONLINE") ? null : define("IS_ONLINE", "online");
```

PHP:

```
print_r(parse_ini_file("config.ini"));
```

Comment: Looks to me like `define` is part of the PHP language, and not part of the informal ini file format. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file Can you point us to a place where `define` is used in this way? In other words: If you want information on how to parse something, you should at least define exactly what that something is.

Comment: I want to list the define values in a table to show for administrate them with inline edit the value of define.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this i can't be a very awesome option but it will work. I have tested it. For receiving file content you should use `$string=file_get_content('config.ini');` instead of example string which i have taken.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/777254)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
/**
* If you do file_get_content('config.ini') that will return you string like this. 
* after this you can do it like this. I am taking a sample string.
**/
$string='[SQL_INFO]
defined("DB_MS") ? null : define("DB_MS", "mysqli");
defined("DB_HOST") ? null : define("DB_HOST", "localhost");

[USER_INFO]
defined("USER_NAME") ? null : define("USER_NAME", "ali");
defined("USER_WEB") ? null : define("USER_WEB", "example.com");

[SITE_INFO]
defined("WEBSITE" null : define("WEBSITE", "example.com");
defined("IS_ONLINE") ? null : define("IS_ONLINE", "online");';

preg_match_all('/define\("(\K[A-Za-z\_]+)"\s*,\s*\"([^"]+)/', $string,$matches);

foreach($matches[1] as $key =>$constant)
{
    defined($constant) ? null: define($constant, $matches[2][$key]);
}
echo DB_HOST;
```

**Solution 2:** Note: it will work if you follow this pattern in which each section is separated by line breakes. Like wise in your post.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$string='[SQL_INFO]
defined("DB_MS") ? null : define("DB_MS", "mysqli");
defined("DB_HOST") ? null : define("DB_HOST", "localhost");

[USER_INFO]
defined("USER_NAME") ? null : define("USER_NAME", "ali");
defined("USER_WEB") ? null : define("USER_WEB", "example.com");

[SITE_INFO]
defined("WEBSITE" null : define("WEBSITE", "example.com");
defined("IS_ONLINE") ? null : define("IS_ONLINE", "online");';

$sections=  preg_split("/[\n]{2,}/", $string);
$requiredInfo='SITE_INFO';//here you can change the section
foreach($sections as $section)
{
    if(preg_match("/\[$requiredInfo\]/", $section,$matches))
    {
        preg_match_all('/define\("(\K[A-Za-z\_]+)"\s*,\s*\"([^"]+)/', $section,$matches);
        foreach($matches[1] as $key =>$constant)
        {
            defined($constant) ? null: define($constant, $matches[2][$key]);
        }
    }
}
echo WEBSITE;
```

Comment: Thank you but this is just return define i always have define i just want to list define options with values and separate them with tags like [SQL_INFO]

Comment: @MAXX3 Try out the second solution hope you will find it helpful.

Comment: ...This is not how you are supposed to go about handling this. Very error prone.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has functions to parse ini files: `parse_ini_file()` or `parse_ini_string()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: yes thank you i know that this function parse ini file with content something like one = 1 but with define have error when reading file so i just need something alternative

Comment: You can't mix in PHP with ini files. Where you would handle the define logic is in the PHP script. So you should have a default ini file, parse it and store it in PHP array. Then in PHP script you run your defined checks. If not defined, then define them.